# How do I check if a Kendo Grid has changes in angular 2+?

Tags: kendo-grid, angular8

I am using editable Kendo grid(few columns contains input controls), I want to alert the user "No changes has been detected" when clicking on "Save" button.

Comment: Please update your post with the code for your grid and any other relevant code as well. This will help others have a better understanding of what you want. Also let us know what you have tried to solve this problem. When exactly are you wanting the "No changes have been detected" message to appear?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I want the message to appear when I click on Save button. I didn't find any code in angular 2+ kendo grid but hasChange() methods are available in kendo grid Jquery